# Can't fix PHP Fatal error: Class 'MongoPool' not found

Tags: mongodb, nginx, php

Unfortunately I'm unable to fix `Class 'MongoPool' not found` error. Rechecked everything in configs and everything looks normal to me :( Spent 4 hours on this already :(

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- nginx 1.1.19
- php 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 as php-fpm extension to nginx
- mongodb driver 1.3.0RC1-dev

Configuration info:

- my phpinfo() output is **[here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jMHq8/show/)**
- nginx.conf is **[here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=npRWDgzJ)**
- fastcgi_params is **[here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tWDMLTZL)**
- php.ini is **[here](http://pastebin.com/ba4gQnwS)**
- php-fpm.conf is **[here](http://pastebin.com/30fmqAvQ)**

mongo.ini in php folder is this

```
extension=mongo.so
mongo.native_long = true
mongo.utf8 = 1
```

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf is pretty short too

```
[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 6
access.log = /var/www/log/$pool.access.log
;chroot = /var/www/
chdir = /
```

Could you please take a look at my configs and help me ?

Test page is this

```
<?php
MongoPool::setSize(2);
?>
```

nginx server's config is

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost 192.168.1.149;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Log snippet from nginx

```
2012/10/21 06:35:48 [error] 21418#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoPool' not found in /usr/share/nginx/www/test2.php on line 2
PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /usr/share/nginx/www/test2.php:0" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /test2.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.1.149"
```

Comment: check output of `print_r(get_declared_classes()); `

Comment: @eicto, sh*t, they removed it ! and didn't say that in documentation ! thank you, thank you!!

Comment: **mongodb driver 1.3.0RC1-dev** - take care when using development versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user **[eicto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/815386/eicto)** hinted above creators of MongoDb Driver for PHP removed this class from trunk version of the driver about 2 months ago (see **[this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/commit/91c4f710f630829f054712046fd5b17103f83152)**).

> We will be adding back MongoPool and couple of the other methods for backwards compatibility, but they won't do anything and just issue E_DEPRECATED warning

Take care when using development versions.

Comment: Yes, you can not instantiate undefined classes, the error you see is typical for an undefined class. The alternative cause of the error is that you the class-name is just wrong, which is not the case in your scenario.